# Print a project name in jinja template

Tags: django, django-models, jinja2

I have the following models

> AcsObject class

```
class AcsObjects(models.Model):
    object_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    object_type = models.ForeignKey('AcsObjectTypes', db_column='object_type')
    context = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    security_inherit_p = models.BooleanField()
    creation_user = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

> Projects class

```
class ImProjects(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('AcsObjects',related_name='project', on_delete=False, primary_key=True)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    project_nr = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

> TimesheetTasks class

```
class TimesheetTasks(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('Projects', related_name='t_task', on_delete=False, primary_key=True)
    uom = models.ForeignKey('Categories', related_name='u_uom', on_delete=False)
    planned_units = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    billable_units = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I wrote the following code into views.py file.

```
class TimesheetData(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'timesheet.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["da"] = TimesheetTasks.objects.all()
        return context
```

I want to print a project_name but it is giving me a task_id ( task_id and project_id are same) using jinja template.

> timesheet.html

```
<body>
<p> {{da}} </p>
<table class="table table-light">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Task </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for timesheet in da %}
        <tr>
            <td> {{timesheet.task}} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

It is giving me a blank output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4DsX.png)

Comment: Please provide your `timesheet.html`

Comment: Hello @ToanQuocHo, I just edited my question, Please refer the above snippet for timesheet.html

Answer (score 0):

That's simply just because you're not access to `product_name` field yet.

```py
<tbody>
    {% for timesheet in da %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{timesheet.task}} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

With this, Jinja just render the task id (project id), because Jinja think that you're not need any other information but just the foreign key value. So to be able to see the `project_name`, you should use this instead: `timesheet.task.project_name`, it does the job.

```py
<tbody>
    {% for timesheet in da %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{timesheet.task.project_name}} </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Just want to mention that this could lead to another issue (performance issue) when Jinja have to query the data when render the template. To get rid of that, consider to use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) which is an API of Django Queryset, check it out and gain some experiment that API, it really useful when using Django.

Comment: `timesheet.task.project_name` will not print the project_name because timesheet.task is not an object of Project class.

Comment: Yes, buddy. It is printing nothing. Is there any other solution?

Comment: That's how I normally do, but without `primary_key=True`, this seem not true when you're consider this field as a primary key. I suggest that you should use another field as a primary key. Or if you want to make this field as primary key, try with OneToOne instead. Let me try on my side, will get back to you soon

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to do that.

Comment: @DipakGiri, I've tried at my side, if you consider `task` as a primary key, so switch to use OneToOneField instead then just apply my answer to show the project name

Comment: When I am trying to add a new project then it is showing me a following error. **Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited**. I think I am missing something.